# When adding form-tags my ajax call wont work, why?

Tags: php, jquery

Im doing this simple ajax call, and i noticed that when adding form tags to my code it breaks the whole ajax response..Just want to know why.

```
<div id="overviewList" class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-1 text-center">
<form>
  <select name="work-progress" class="work-progress" id="work-progress">
    <option selected>Visa</option>
    <option value="1">Startade arbeten</option>
    <option value="2">Halvfärdiga projekt</option>
    <option value="3">Pausade projekt</option>
    <option value="4">Färdiga projekt</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="show-progress">Välj arbetsflöde</button>
</form>
</div>
```

And then the ajax call

```
$("#show-progress").click(function(){
var workProgress = $( "#work-progress option:selected" ).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/show-progress.php",
    data: {workProgress:workProgress},
    dataType:"JSON",
    success: function(data){

      var html = '';
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>' +value.id+ '</td>';
        html += '<td>' +value.workMessage+ '</td>';
        html += '<td>' +value.userID+ '</td>';
        html += '<td>' +value.timestamp+ '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
      });
      $("#resultsTable").append(html);

    }
  }); // Ajax ends
  $("#resultsTable").val("").html("");
```

});

Comment: Because clicking the _submit_ button _submits_ the form, and you did nothing to prevent that. So the browser submits the form normally, and shows the result as a new document, discarding any AJAX requests that might still be going on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the default of the form submission. By default the form sends a HTTP Request of the type you have described in the `method` attribute to the `action` URL.

To prevent this call `event.preventDefault()` in your handler:

```
$("#show-progress").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  /* ... */
});
```